# Conditional Gaussian distribution given two dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Consider the following problem:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    X \\
    U \\
\end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
    \mu_x \\
    0 \\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_x^2 & 0 \\
    0 & \sigma_u^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\right) \\
\\\
\\\
W = X + U
$$

We want to find $E[X|W]$.

Here is my solution that I think is correct:

$$
W \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2 + \sigma_u^2)\\
\\\
\\\
E[W] = \mu_x \\\
\\\
\text{COV}(X, W) = \text{COV}(W, X) = \text{VAR}(X) + \text{COV}(U, X) = \sigma_x^2 \\
\\\
\\\
E[X|W] = E\left[\frac{p(X,W)}{p(W)}\right] = E\left[\frac{
\mathcal{N}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
    \mu_x \\
    \mu_x \\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_x^2 & \sigma_x^2 \\
    \sigma_x^2 & \sigma_x^2 + \sigma_u^2  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
}{\mathcal{N}(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2 + \sigma_u^2)}\right] = E\left[\mathcal{N}\left(\mu_z, \sigma_z^2\right)\right] = \mu_z
$$

Where

$$
\mu_z = \mu_x + \frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_u^2} (w_i - \mu_x) \\
\\\
\\\ 
\sigma_z^2 = \sigma_x^2 - \frac{\sigma_x^2\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_u^2}
$$

The problem where is that it also seems intuitive that $E[X|W=w_i] = w_i$ because $W = X + U$ and $E[U] = 0$ and so my intuition says the correct answers should be something like $\mu_z = \mu_x + (w_i - \mu_x)$. Is my intuition wrong or did I make a mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: What does $ E\left[\frac{
\mathcal{N}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
    \mu_x \\
    \mu_x \\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_x^2 & \sigma_x^2 \\
    \sigma_x^2 & \sigma_x^2 + \sigma_u^2  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
}{\mathcal{N}(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2 + \sigma_u^2)}\right]$ even mean?  Is that a ratio of densities and if so then how do you take its expectation?

Comment: It appears to be a shorthand notation for "the expectation of the (conditional) distribution"

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/intuitive-explanation-of-contribution-to-sum-of-two-normally-distributed-random

Comment: @Henry it is the expected value of the conditional probability. I.e. E[p(X, W) / p(W)]

Comment: DanielOliveira - it is not quite that as it is the conditional expectation of a random variable rather than of a probability : @GrahamKemp's explanation was closer

Comment: @Henry I understand, but in this case, since the random variables are Gaussian we can think of them as probabilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is off.  Although $\mathsf E(U)=0$, it need not be that $\mathsf E(U\mid W)$ is so.$$\mathsf E(W\mid W)=\mathsf E(X\mid W)+\mathsf E(U\mid W)$$

---

$$\mathsf E(X\mid W)= \dfrac{\sigma^2_X W+\sigma_U^2\mu_X}{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_U^2}\\ \mathsf E(U\mid W)=\dfrac{\sigma_U^2(W-\mu_X)}{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_U^2}$$

Comment: +1.  This could also be written as $\mathbb E[X\mid W] = \mu_X + (W - \mu_X) \dfrac{\sigma^2_X }{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_U^2}$ and $\mathbb E[U\mid W] =  (W - \mu_X) \dfrac{\sigma^2_U }{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_U^2}$ or in handwaving words that the excess of $W$ over $\mathbb E[W]$ is expected to be distributed between $X$ and $U$ in proportion to their original variances

Comment: @Henry yes it seems intuitive when thought that way. I got the same result as you but my intuition was wrong.